# Center image in ul

Tags: html, css

Tried to google this but didn't find anything that helped me.
So I have button-text on the left and right but I want to center an image inside the top bar.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    }

    li {
    float: left;
    }

    li a {
    display: block;
    color: #666;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }

    li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #ddd;
    }

    li a.active {
    color: white;
    background-color: #3744a2;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="../index.html">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="../news/news.html">news</a></li>
    <li><a href="../services/services.html">services</a></li>
    <li><a class="active" href="#">prices</a></li>
    <li><a href="../contat/contat.html">contat</a></li>
    <li><a class="image" href="#"><img src="https://dummyimage.com/150X38/000/fff"></a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="mailto:enter@email.here"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; enter@email.here</a></li>
    <li style="float:right"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; 123 123 123</a></li>
    </ul>
```

so what I basicly want is the image (class="image") to be centered, but the rest as it is.

Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it like this

Remove `image` class from `a` tag and give `image` class to it's parent `li` and try this with this example. it will helps you

```css
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: #f3f3f3;
text-align: center;
}

li {
float: left;
}

li a {
display: block;
color: #666;
text-align: center;
padding: 14px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
background-color: #ddd;
}

li a.active {
color: white;
background-color: #3744a2;
}
li.image {
    float: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
<li><a href="../index.html">home</a></li>
<li><a href="../news/news.html">news</a></li>
<li><a href="../services/services.html">services</a></li>
<li><a class="active" href="#">prices</a></li>
<li><a href="../contat/contat.html">contat</a></li>
<li class='image'><a class="" href="#"><img src="../image/image.png"></a></li>
<li style="float:right"><a href="mailto:enter@email.here"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; enter@email.here</a></li>
<li style="float:right"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; 123 123 123</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a.image {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto 
}
```

try adding that code in your css file . Also try have a look [here](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html) 
it has more info about centering things .

Answer (score 0):

I used display:flex and flex property. by setting display: flex:0 I'm telling the browser I want this element take just the place he need, and with flex:1 on a single element I'm telling that I want it to take all the possible place

```css
div.nav {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
  display: flex;
  }

  div.left-part, div.right-part {
    flex: 0;
    display:inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
  }

  div.center-part {
    flex: 1;
    text-align: center;
  }


  div.nav-button {
  display:inline-block;
  }

  div.nav-button a {
  display: block;
  color: #666;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  }

  div.nav-button a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #ddd;
  }

  div.nav-button a.active {
  color: white;
  background-color: #3744a2;
  }
```

```html
<div class="nav">
  <div class="left-part"><div class="nav-button"><a href="../index.html">home</a></div>
    <div class="nav-button"><a href="../news/news.html">news</a></div>
    <div class="nav-button"><a href="../services/services.html">services</a></div>
    <div class="nav-button"><a class="active" href="#">prices</a></div>
    <div class="nav-button"><a href="../contat/contat.html">contat</a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="center-part">
    <div class="nav-button"><a class="image" href="#"><img src="../image/image.png"></a></div>
  </div>
  <div class="right-part">
    <div class="nav-button"><a href="mailto:enter@email.here"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; enter@email.here</a></div>
    <div class="nav-button"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-phone" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp; 123 123 123</a></div>
  </div>
</div>
```